# my target frame does not open within my page, instead it opens in a separate window/tab. What gives?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, formidable

**Use Case: displaying info in a subset window of the SAME page the user is in. For example. I have a list on the left side. On the right side is details of a record based on what data point is clicked on the left. Currently I am trying to use an iframe tag. Both parent and target iframe are content from my single same domain/site i.e. there is no external sources I'm referencing.**

I've had this iframe working in the past, then one day I went to check it out and it was not working as it should.

So the parent page has a list of students (in the left column).
The target iframe (right column) is supposed to show the students details one the students link is clicked in the parent page.

Instead what it's doing now, is opening a whole new tab in a separate window with the students details.

UPDATE: Jan16, 2018
So i tested it in four browsers. Only **Safari** apparently supports the inwindow target render. Chrome, Opera and Firefox all opened new tabs - not what i want. What gives? Here is the full html (I realized I should grab the source vs what my front end html looks like in Wordpress... sorry).

```
 <p><iframe id="ifrm" src="http://example/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpbc&#038;wh_approved&#038;wh_is_new=1&#038;wh_booking_date=3&#038;view_mode=vm_listing" width="100%" height="400">Your school has not setup a booking listings view. Please speak to your school or contact admin to have it set up.
</iframe></p>
<p>Welcome Instructor. This is your personal Dashboard. 
<p><strong>School Name:</strong> School name <br />
<strong>Your ID:</strong> instructor3</p>
<hr />
<div class="fivecol-one"><strong>Student ID:</strong> user<br />
<a href="http://example/frm_display/Instructor-dashboard-iframe?student=453369" target="myiframe">View Details in window<br />
</a></p>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp;<strong>Student ID:</strong> jan17<br />
<a href="http://example/frm_display/Instructor-dashboard-iframe?student=45988" target="myiframe">View Details in window<br />
</a></p>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp;<strong>Student ID:</strong> user2<br />
<a href="http://example/frm_display/Instructor-dashboard-iframe?student=44499" target="myiframe">View Details in window<br />
</a></p>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp;<strong>Student ID:</strong> jstudent<br />
<a href="http://example/frm_display/Instructor-dashboard-iframe?student=464428" target="myiframe">View Details in window<br />
</a></p>
<hr />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="fivecol-four last">
<iframe id="myiframe" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" src="http://example/frm_display/Instructor-dashboard-iframe/" height="500px" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

So you can see that I have named my iframe id="myiframe" and my target="myiframe". I did notice that i had forgotten to close the iframe tag in the target, however, that did not seem to make a difference. I cleared my cache and refreshed my pages.

As mentioned it's working in Safari desktop only. HOWEVER, (and this is weird) in mobile, it's working in ALL browsers! (i removed my explicative..what was i thinking)

I don't know if this is applicable, but this site is hosted in Wordpress and using formidable forms. In particular the iframe is displaying what's called in formidable a 'view' i.e. a special page that shows data from formidable. It's not formally a 'page' in the Wordpress sense of the meaning. Hence I'm wondering if for some reason the iframe tag is getting confused. One suggestion was to use 
    
in the header of the iframe page. And that's when i realized i can't apparently do that because as far as I know a formidable 'view' does not have a header?

HELP!!! please.

Comment: You should consider asking this question in: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: instead of providing shortcodes, provide full code of section, which we can to reproduce

Comment: You need to post the HTML code of the link which is supposed to open/change the iframe content

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Duly noted for the sub stack suggestion. Just learned how to add code properly. Sorry about that. Should be better now.

Comment: Btw it's not really a WP question (apologises for tagging it such). It's a generic iframe question.

Answer (score 0):

this is embarrassing.
I was simply missing a name attribute
    name="myIframe"
wow... sorry for posting bone head move, but hope it can help someone.